# Trying to modify a global variable using a function

Tags: javascript, function

```
var age=25;

function modify(a) { 
  a=30; 
}

modify(age); 
console.log(age)
```

I wish to modify the `age` which is a global variable passing the parameter to the function which I'm not able to do so. I'm still trying to learn javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want to modify the global based on the param variable passed to the function. As in `modify(age)` and now `age` is 30. This isn't possible in any language i know of except Pascal. Well PHP too or any language that allows vars by reference.

Answer (score 1):

it's pass by value in case of scalar data. So it won't change the age value. If you want to change it then use object or array.

Comment: Was what i likely meant by above comment. Has to be a by reference data type for the change to happen since both param and inner variable point to the same. Upvoted.

Comment: To prevent future misunderstandings, "pass by value" has nothing to do with what kind of value is passed. Everything is pass by value in JavaScript. However, in case of an object the value is a reference, and that makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing a variable to a function, the function creates a local variable whose scope is bounted to that function. That variable will never point to the actual variable that you used. In order to achieve this you need to assign the respinse from that function to your variable.

In your case the global variable `age` and the local variable `a` inside the function `modify` points to different memory address. So updating the local variable inside the function will never updates the global variable.

You can achieve this is multiple ways. You can return the value from that function and assign that to the global varible as a work around

```js
var age=25;
function modify(a) {
  a = 30;
  return a;
}
age = modify(age);
console.log(age)
```

Or else you could directly update the value of the global variable from the function. In this scenario you are pointing to the global variable address itself.

```js
var age=25;
function modify(a) {
  age = 30;
}
modify(age);
console.log(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var age=25;

function modify(a) { return a=30 };

console.log(modify(age)); // logs 30

console.log(age); // still 25
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the value of `a`

If you want to update age inside your function you must point to the var `age`

```js
age = 30
```

```js
// declared var age and assign 25
var age = 25;

console.log("Initial value of age: ", age)

function modify(a) { 
  //here, within the function you have a variable 'a'
  console.log('value of a inside the function ', a)
  // you update the value of 'a' with 30
  // you never modify the value of age.
  a=30; 
  console.log("value of a after updating it: ", a)
  // because you declared age in the global scope you get access to it
  // to update age you must do
  age = 30
}

modify(age); 
console.log('final value of age: ', age)
```